# Paginate google book search results

Tags: javascript, html

I ve a problem with the pagination of the search results in Javascript, my code show me in the dom the all results for a determinate word but i need to paginate these in different pages in 5 elements by page. when i try to call the element **totalItems** it gives me the error the element is not defined. can someone help me please?

```
    function getBooks(search) {
  bookSearch(search, start);
}
function bookSearch(search, start){
  var search = document.getElementById('search').value
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = ""
  
  $.ajax({

    url:"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + search + "&maxResults=40&start=" + start,
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data){
      totalItems = data.items;
 
      if(data.items){
      for(i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++){
        if(data.items[i].volumeInfo){
           var title = data.items[i].volumeInfo.title
           var subtitle = data.items[i].volumeInfo.subtitle
           var img = data.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail
           var date = data.items[i].volumeInfo.publishedDate
           var info = data.items[i].volumeInfo.infoLink
          results.innerHTML += 
          '<div class="card my-3" style="max-width: 540px;">'+
          '<div class="row no-gutters">'+
          '<div class="col-md-4">'+
          '<img src="'+img+'" class="card-img-top img-card" alt="...">'+
          '</div>'+
          '<div class="col-md-8">'+
          '<div class="card-body">'+
          '<h5 class="card-title">'+title+'</h5>'+
          '<p class="card-text subtitle">'+ subtitle  +'</p>'+
          '<p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">'+ date +'</small></p>'+
          '<a href="'+info +'"target="_blank" class="btn bg-main text-second info">Book Info</a>'+
          '</div>'+
          '</div>'+
          '</div>'+
          '</div>'
        }
        numberOfPages = getNumberOfPages();
      }  
      if(totalItems > 40){
        start+=40;
        bookSearch("", start);
      }
    }
  },
  type: 'GET'
});
}
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', bookSearch, false)

function load() {
  bookSearch();
  loadTotalItems();
}

var list = totalItems;
var numberPerPage = 5;
var pageList = new Array();
var currentPage = 1;
var numberOfPages = 0;



function getNumberOfPages(){
  return Math.ceil(list.length / numberPerPage)
}

function nextPage(){

  currentPage +=1;
  loadTotalItems();
}

function previousPage() {
  currentPage -= 1;
  loadTotalItems();
}

function firstPage() {
  currentPage = 1;
  loadTotalItems();
}

function lastPage() {
  currentPage = numberOfPages;
  loadTotalItems();
}

function loadTotalItems() {
  var begin = ((currentPage - 1) * numberPerPage);
  var end = begin + numberPerPage;

  pageList = list.slice(begin, end);
  bookSearch();
  check();
}


function check() {
  document.getElementById("next").disabled = currentPage == numberOfPages ? true : false;
  document.getElementById("previous").disabled = currentPage == 1 ? true : false;
  document.getElementById("first").disabled = currentPage == 1 ? true : false;
  document.getElementById("last").disabled = currentPage == numberOfPages ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: `var totalItems = data.items;`

Comment: it doesn't work because totalItems and data.items are in the local scope of the bookSearch function

Comment: `var totalItems = data.items;` - you forgot `var`

Comment: Then declare the variable as null outside of the function and set it in the function

Comment: @AndyRay that doesn't fix the scoping problem

Comment: i've done it but doesn't work. it's still showing all the results

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable outside of the function to make it have a global scope:

```
var totalItems;
function bookSearch(search, start){
  $.ajax({
    success: function(data) {
      totalItems = data.items;
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: It's very difficult to understand your question. Could you try explaining it differently? What exactly isn't working and what do you expect?

Comment: Im expecting the datas from the cycle for will be paginate by 5 elements in the total number of page.

Comment: @FabrizioGuerrieri "for will be paginate by 5 elements" make no sense. Try separating the sentence into several sentences.

Comment: e.g. total items for the search result / number of elements per page = total page.              basically i have to split the results of book search in 5 elements per page.

Comment: basically when I do a search for a book, it shows me all the results related to the search. I have to split the results into an assigned number of items per page e.g. for one word it shows me 40 results and I have to layout the results in 5 elements for the total number of pages needed for all elements. @Rojo